# Can't run AND bank testbench?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

This is my code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY AND_Bank_Test IS
END AND_Bank_Test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF AND_Bank_Test IS 

 -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT AND_Bank
PORT(
        Input : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     AND_Bit : IN  std_logic;
        Output : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs

signal Input : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal AND_Bit : std_logic := '0';

--Outputs

signal Output : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

-- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with 
   -- appropriate port name 


BEGIN
-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)

uut: AND_Bank PORT MAP (
      Input => Input,
      AND_Bit => AND_Bit,
      Output => Output
    );

   -- Stimulus process

   stim_proc: process
    begin       
-- hold reset state for 100 ns.

    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "00000001" ; AND_Bit <= 0; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "00111011" ; AND_Bit <= 1; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "10111011" ; AND_Bit <= 0; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "10110011" ; AND_Bit <= 1; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "01110111" ; AND_Bit <= 0; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "10110000" ; AND_Bit <= 1; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "11110011" ; AND_Bit <= 0; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "01110011" ; AND_Bit <= 1; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "10111111" ; AND_Bit <= 0; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "11111111" ; AND_Bit <= 1; 
    wait for 100 ns;    
wait;
end process;

END;
```

And this is the error I get:

`Type std_logic does not match with the integer literal
(this refers to Input <= "00000001" ; AND_Bit <= 0; )`

I've replaced my code with this:

ENTITY AND_Bank_Test IS
END AND_Bank_Test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF AND_Bank_Test IS

```
COMPONENT AND_Bank
PORT(
        Input : IN  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
     AND_Bit : IN  std_logic;
        Output : OUT  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
    );
```

END COMPONENT;

--Inputs

```
signal Input : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal AND_Bit : std_logic := '0';

--Outputs

signal Output : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
```

BEGIN

```
-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)

uut: AND_Bank PORT MAP (
      Input => Input,
      AND_Bit => AND_Bit,
      Output => Output
    );
```

-- Stimulus process

stim_proc: process
    begin
-- hold reset state for 100 ns.

```
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000000000001" ; AND_Bit <= '0'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000000111011" ; AND_Bit <= '1'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000010111011" ; AND_Bit <= '0'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000010110011" ; AND_Bit <= '1'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000001110111" ; AND_Bit <= '0'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000010110000" ; AND_Bit <= '1'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000011110011" ; AND_Bit <= '0'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000001110011" ; AND_Bit <= '1'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000010111111" ; AND_Bit <= '0'; 
    wait for 100 ns;    

    Input <= "0000000011111111" ; AND_Bit <= '1'; 
    wait for 100 ns;
```

wait;
end process;

END;

is this the correct way to run a AND bank test?
why can't run it with only 8 bits?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a single quote, e.g.:

```
Input <= "00000001" ; AND_Bit <= '0';
```

If you are not using a single quote, it assumes you are assigning an integer value to `AND_Bit`, which is why it is giving you an error.

Comment: i've changed to 
Input <= "00000001" ; AND_Bit <= '0';

and the error i get now is 
Input : IN  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
error(Expression has 8 elements ; expected 16)

same for the Output : OUT  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)

Comment: It appears you have changed the width of your inputs/outputs. Are you still having a problem as the question appears? What you are asking is becoming muddied.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error, `AND_Bit` is std_logic.You have to write `AND_BIT <= '0';` in your test-bench instead of `AND_BIT <= 0;` This is the reason why simulator considering `0` as an integer instead of a bit. For second error in your comments, you changed the size of `IN and OUT`, which is 16 bits but in the test-bench you are giving 8 bits as Input. So change the size accordingly.

Comment: i've changed to Input <= "00000001" ; AND_Bit <= '0'; and the error i get now is Input : IN std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); error(Expression has 8 elements ; expected 16) same for the Output : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) thats why I changed my input and output in my second code to 16 bits

Comment: That means somewhere in your program, the size of mapping ports is not matching. You have to check size of `IN` and `OUT` in each module (AND & test-bench etc).